# Problema en C basico

Tags: c, dev-c++, codeblocks

estoy aprendiendo a programar en C y nos dejaron un trabajo que hacer, pero al querer compilar me sale un error y por lo que sé hasta el momento aun no sé cual es el error . Gracias de antemano y perdon si es una pregunta muy pendeja, sigo aprendiendo. 
 error: expected ')' before ':' token|

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int codigo, costo, valor;
    float minutos;
    cout<< "Ingrese codigo de area: ";
    cin>> codigo;
    cout<< "Ingrese duracion de llamada: ";
    cin>> minutos;

    if (minutos <=1:00)
        minutos = 1;
    else if (minutos =2:00)
        minutos = 2;
    else if (minutos <=3:00)
        minutos = 3;
    else if (minutos <=4:00)
       minutos = 4;
    else if (minutos <=5:00)
        minutos = 5;

    switch(valor){
        case 8: valor = 6;
        break;
        case 12: valor = 4;
        break;
        case 15: valor = 8;
        break;
        case 20: valor = 6;
        break;
        case 22: valor = 7;
        break;

    }

    costo = minutos*valor




    }


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone que se ha de indicar la duración de la llamada? ¿`2:00`?, ¿`2.0`?, ¿otro formato? Concreta los detalles para que te podamos dar una respuesta.

Comment: Dos cosas.
1. El formato en que intentas comprar no es correcto, < 2:00 > no es un numero correspondiente a float.
2. Al momento del < switch(valor) > la variable valor que valor tendira ? o.O

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que sera porque en el condicional no puedes comparar un valor como 2:00 con un entero, deberia ser algo como if (minutos == 2) no en un formato de hora

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. En este portal se espera que las respuestas sean concisas y concretas. Empezar con un _supongo_ no es algo que denote especial seguridad. Por otro lado, considera incluir código que muestre cómo corregir el error desde tu punto de vista.